# Groovy each method returning incorrect results

Tags: java, types, groovy, closures, inference

In a bit of Groovy code I had written the line

```
def intCurrentArray = currentVersion.tokenize('.').each({x -> Integer.parseInt(x)})
```

which parses a string formatted like a version number XX.XX.XX.XX and converts the resulting list of strings to a list of integers.  However, Groovy inferred intCurrentArray to be a list of strings instead, causing an incorrect conversion.  When I changed the line to:

```
ArrayList intCurrentArray = []
for (x in currentVersion.tokenize('.'))
   intCurrentArray.add(Integer.parseInt(x))
```

the conversion worked just fine.  Why would the each method give funky results? Does Groovy not look inside the closure to help infer the type of intCurrentArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` returns the same list it iterated. Use `collect` instead to build a new list from each result of the closure passed as argument:

```
def intCurrentArray = "99.88.77.66".tokenize('.').collect { it.toInteger() }

assert intCurrentArray == [99, 88, 77, 66]
```

Or the spread operator:

```
def intCurrentArray = "99.88.77.66".tokenize('.')*.toInteger()
```

Comment: So to clarify, each must return a list of the same type that you pass as argument? You don't mean that each returns the list unchanged? That wouldn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yes. `each` does return the same list from which it was invoked, unchanged. What you want is to `collect` the result of applying your closure on each element.